# Getting constant error for all flutter projects Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Launching lib\main.dart on RMX2001 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Multiple build operations failed.
> Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
> Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
> Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
> Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
> Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
> Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
> Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
> Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
> Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
> Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried disabling antivirus but problem is still same

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

change you compileSdkVersion version to 33
file:

```
android/app/build.gradle
```

```dart
buildscript {
    ext {
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 31
    }
```